# What happened to the standard components like grids, radio buttons, button in Angular 7

Tags: html, angular7

https://angular.io/tutorial
I am using the above library to get up to speed on Angular 7 but can't find any information like grids, tables, buttons etc like they had in Angualr 1.x. Can someone please post what happened to the standard components and examples of using them or even just the HTML code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In the future in order to receive more responses or info on your problem it is recommended that you include a code sample or a more specific instance so that you can get better responses.

Answer (score 1):

Angular Material is kind of Angulars Answer to bootstrap. You can still use bootstrap if you wanted to of course. Id recommend you take a look here
https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview
You dont have to use Angular material you could find any other kind of table package and get going with it. Since Angular is now a full front end framework you can install pretty much any NPM package and get going.

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
```

Comment: What other packages are there and if I don't want to use angular material, do I create my own components?

Comment: The world is your oyster with NPM. Heres another datatable you can take a look at https://medium.com/apprendre-le-web-avec-lior/angular-5-and-jquery-datatables-fd1dd2d81d99